# \bfseries does not work for CJK characters with \songti font in .cls file

Tags: bold, xecjk

I am modifying an existing thesis template.

In the `.cls` file, `\bfseries` does not work for CJK characters with `\songti`, `\lishu`, `\heiti` or other similar settings, but works for numbers, CJK characters with the CJK main font i.e. `Adobe Fangsong Std` and other Non-CJK characters.

A MWE is showing below:

The `mythesis.cls` file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mythesis}

\LoadClass{ctexbook}

\RequirePackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra}
\RequirePackage{xeCJK}
\xeCJKsetup{xeCJKactive=true}
\xeCJKsetup{AutoFakeBold=4}
\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Fangsong Std}

\renewcommand\maketitle{
    \zihao{-0}\bfseries{测试1a}\mdseries{测试1a} \par
    \songti\bfseries{测试1a}\mdseries{测试1a}
}
```

The `mythesis.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{mythesis}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: The result]

BTW: this modification is only for personal use.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to change the class file? Just because you are allowed to use a copy of it, you may not be allowed to change it. It is someones property, there is a copyright and a license.

Comment: The question in its current state can only be answered using a crystal ball. There are information missing, especially a mnimal working example.

Comment: It has a MIT license. https://github.com/XBWer/Thesis-SE-ZJU-LaTeX

Comment: For personal use, it can always be modified I think. But not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your generous helps, I added a small snippet.

Comment: snippets make it very hard for anyone to help, far better would be to make a small complete document using a generally available class that produces the same problem

Comment: A MWE is added. @DavidCarlisle